# Обновлять программно свойство не вызывая рекурсию

Tags: c#, wpf, ооп

Имеются два свойства, на которые привязаны два  TextBox. Пример свойств, как сейчас:

```
public int P1
{
    get { return _p1; }
    set
    {
        _p1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("P1"));
        P2 += 2;
    }
}

public int P2
{
    get { return _p2; }
    set
    {
        _p2 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("P2"));
        P1 += 1;
    }
}
```

В разметке:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding P1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding P2, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Необходимо, например, при изменении свойства P1 через TextBox менять значение свойсва P2, но сделать это таким образом, чтобы при обновлении P2, в данном случае, не обновлялось P1 потому как изменение произошло не через TextBox, а внутри кода. Подскажите, как это правильней было бы сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Избежать рекурсии просто, достаточно устанавливать значение не через сеттер-свойства, а через поле и вызывать `OnPropertyChanged("имя_свойства")`.

Такой подход не требует никаких флагов

```
    int _p1;
    public int P1
    {
        get { return _p1; }
        set 
        { 
            _p1 = value;
            _p2 += 2;
            OnPropertyChanged("P1"));
            OnPropertyChanged("P2"));
        }
    }

    int _p2;
    public int P2
    {
        get { return _p2; }
        set
        {
            _p2 = value;
            _p1 += 1;

            OnPropertyChanged("P1"));
            OnPropertyChanged("P2"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Флажок сделай.

```
fl = 1;
P2 += 2;
fl = 0;
...
set{
...
if (fl = 0)
  P1 += 1;
...
}
```

Comment: Это какой язык программирования?